# Php exec failed but module working fine on cmdline

Tags: php, opencv, web

I have a xampp setup and im calling an opencv module from php `exec` function which has been tested to work fine on the system. But when I call it with php, it fails with the result as a random negative number.

For example: `-1073741819`

Further investigation lead to the conclusion that the culprit was `libtesseract302.dll` but it just seems to work fine from the cmdline on the same system and not on xampp.

Comment: I'd suspect a type conversion error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid adding unnecessary (although polite) words and phrases to posts.

Comment: Could it be because this module writes files to c drive where xampp is installed and might not have sufficient privilege.?